# how to merge spark row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Hi i have a DataSet of Track.class i want to merge all tracks that are within same interval of time for example 5 min .i.e any tracks start after a track that ends within 5 min before will be the same track.its look like fusion task.

my input :

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  trackId |  start_time    |  end_time                  |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1       | 12:00:00       |   12:04:00                 |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  2       | 12:05:00       |   12:08:00                 |  
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  3       | 12:20:00       |   12:22:00                 | 
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
```

output :(trackId  : 1,2 are been merged since diff of start and end of each one is  within 5 min)

```
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  trackId |  start_time    |  end_time                  |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------+
|  1       | 12:00:00       |  12:08:00                  |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  3       | 12:20:00       |   12:22:00                 |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

so how  can i do that ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please provide more details on what have you tried so far and what did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rank()` with `groupBy()`. Here is the query you may want to think of running using spark. The below query is to give you an idea and it is not tried and tested.

```
select trackId,start_tim,end_time,
       start_time-end_time as difference,
       rank () over (order by difference asc) as rank
from table_name
where rank=1
group by difference;
```